# syntaxerror missing } after property list

Tags: ajax

```
<script>
function changeProgram(val){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getSemester?pro=NULL",
            data: {pro:  val, staff_id: $('#staff_id').val(),
            success: function(data) {

                var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(new_data.length>0 ){
                    var dom ="<option value=''>SELECT</option>";

                    for(var index = 0; index < new_data.length; index++) {
                        dom += "<option value='"+new_data[index].SM_SEMESTER_CODE+"'>"+new_data[index].STOTAL+" - "+new_data[index].SM_SEMESTER_DESC+"</option>"; 

                    }
                    $(".semesterGroup").html(dom);

                 }else{
                     var dom ="<option value=''>SELECT</option>";
                     $(".semesterGroup").html(dom);
                 }
            }
     });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix.

Just a missing bracket on this line

```
data: {pro:  val, staff_id: $('#staff_id').val()} <---  ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing } for data:

Here is the solution code -

```
function changeProgram(val){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getSemester?pro=NULL",
        data: {pro:  val, staff_id: $('#staff_id').val()},
        success: function(data) {

            var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(new_data.length>0 ){
                var dom ="<option value=''>SELECT</option>";

                for(var index = 0; index < new_data.length; index++) {
                    dom += "<option value='"+new_data[index].SM_SEMESTER_CODE+"'>"+new_data[index].STOTAL+" - "+new_data[index].SM_SEMESTER_DESC+"</option>";

                }
                $(".semesterGroup").html(dom);

            }else{
                var dom ="<option value=''>SELECT</option>";
                $(".semesterGroup").html(dom);
            }
        }
    });
}
```